# Excel Formula to Calculate Sum of Time Duration Between a Specific Time Frame

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to calculate the total number of hours between two columns of start and end times but only those hours that fall between 9:00am and 5:00pm, Monday to Friday.

For example, my data looks something like this:

```
Date      | Start Time | End Time | Duration
Wednesday | 930        | 1400     | 4.50
Thursday  | 930        | 1300     | 3.50
Saturday  | 800        | 1600     | 8.00
Sunday    | 1000       | 1200     | 2.00
Tuesday   | 730        | 1400     | 6.50
Friday    | 930        | 1900     | 9.50
```

So I need to add up how many hours this space was used, but only those hours from 9:00am to 5:00pm and only between Monday to Friday. Is there a formula I could construct for this?

Comment: the IF condition should help

Comment: I found my answer after a lot of tinkering. I had to set reference cells with start and end times and add a new helper column, but I used this:

=IF(WEEKDAY(I10,2)<6, (F10-((IF((('COU Summary'!$G$4-(TIME(INT(D10/100),D10-INT(D10/100)*100,0)))*24)>0,('COU Summary'!$G$4-(TIME(INT(D10/100),D10-INT(D10/100)*100,0)))*24,0))+IF((((TIME(INT(E10/100),E10-INT(E10/100)*100,0))-'COU Summary'!$H$4)*24)>0,((TIME(INT(E10/100),E10-INT(E10/100)*100,0))-'COU Summary'!$H$4)*24,0))), 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below formula.

```
=IF([End Time]>TIME(17,0,0),TIME(17,0,0),[End Time])-IF([Start Time]<TIME(9,0,0),TIME(9,0,0),[Start Time])
```

It will replace End Times with 17:00 and Start Times with 09:00 if the End Time is later than 5 PM or the Start Time is earlier than 9 AM. If the Start Time and End Times are on different sides of midnight (e.g. Start = 17:00, End = 04:00) you will need to adjust the formula to account for that.